# ASP.NET AJAX Timer on iOS Safari

Tags: asp.net, iphone, asp.net-ajax, safari

I'm attempting to display a real-time Arrivals/Departures list on an iPad / iPod Touch / iPhone that automatically refreshes every few seconds. ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels work fine, but the AJAX Timer never fires in iOS Safari browsers.

Is there a way to get an ASP.NET AJAX Timer to work on iOS devices? Or is there some way I can put a bit of manual JS in there for these browsers that trigger the timer's Tick event?